# Java Unix script execution thread sleep behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java web-app application which executes native unix bash script using ProcessBuilder and my unix script has wait & sleep logic on external resources.

There are instances when app hangs intermittently and I suspect unix-script execution could be one of the reason behind this.

**Java Code Sample:**

```
public static void resourceCheck(String arg) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] cmd = { "sh", "/usr/hdf/current/nifi/custom_scripts/resExec.sh",arg};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            p.getInputStream()));
   //Get results and log
}
```

**Bash Script snippet**

```
while [ ! -f ${watcher_file} ]
do
    echo -e `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`" : Watcher file ${watcher_file} not created yet.\nWaiting for ${wait_timer} seconds" | tee -a "${LOG_FILE}"
    sleep ${wait_timer}
done
```

Based on my experience I have huge number of java Thread.sleep without impacting application but I am not sure what happens unix script has thread sleep.

can you please explain how exactly it works when Java Process builder triggers a unix script which has thread sleep and any potential issues with this approach?

Comment: Nothing special.  They are running in two separate processes.  Since you haven't shown your code or the script, we really can't offer more than that. You haven't even told us what you mean by "Unix script" (bash, perl, python??).

Comment: @JimGarrison please review now.. It is a shell script I have added code snippet.

Comment: If the condition in the shell script is never satisfied, the script will never return and your Java thread will never get past the `waitFor()`.  Can you explain why you think this shouldn't be the case?

Comment: Code snippet is portion of my script. We have another piece of logic that take cares of terminating this process if it won't complete within X time. I am trying to understand let's say i just have 4 cores vm and this script is executed too many times in parallel and sleeps for atleast 5 mins then would there be any issues? how many processes can be executed in parallel?

Comment: Well, that's a pretty critical piece of the puzzle... please show/explain how you handle timeouts.

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. I tried to share oversimplified version of actual process. This code runs under a product called `Apache NIFI` there we have a check if process takes beyond X mins then stop it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229358/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-jim-garrison).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `waitFor` AFTER reading the process stdout stream, not before. Also Java `exec` calls can hang if your app does not consume the STDOUT / STDERR streams properly though its not clear whether your sub-process writes a lot. It's easier to fix this if you switch to ProcessBuilder and merge STDERR to STDOUT with:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
try(var stdout = p.getInputStream()) {
   stdout.transferTo(System.out);  // or wherever
}
int rc = p.waitFor();
```

It's not a good idea to use this type of call (ie something which sleeps in the calling thread) in some web-applications - for example if this is triggered by a servlet request and there are multiple clients you could end up with all the requests blocking the web-application server while all threads are doing essentially the same wait - and leaving no threads to handle new connections.

Comment: Thank you. This make sense.